# Виртуальность, наследование и указатель на массив в C++

Tags: наследование, c++

Доброго здоровья всем!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть класс Parent, есть класс Child. С помощью виртуальных функций определёны некие различия в базовом классе и классе-наследнике.
Есть третий класс Foo. Создаются несколько объектов Foo. В зависимости от конструктора, нужно, чтобы объект содержал массив Parent или Child. Я пытался это реализовать созданием в классе Foo поля

```
Parent **pointer;
```

Конструкторы для простоты вот такие:

```
Foo::Foo()
{
   pointer = new Parent * [5];
}
Foo::Foo(int)
{
  pointer = new Child * [5];
}
```

Соответственно, при компиляции получаю ошибку "foo.cpp:10: ошибка: invalid conversion from 'Child**' to 'Parent**' [-fpermissive]".
Как побороть эту проблему?

Comment: @Евгений Василенко, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: как оригианльно, код как обычный текст, обычный текст как код

Comment: @Rules, подправил правильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `new (Parent*)[5]` в обоих случаях. Вы сможете положить `Child*` в массив `Parent*`-ов.

---

Давайте я объясню, почему вы не сможете присвоить массиву указателей на `Parent` массив указателей на `Child`. Предположим на секундочку, что вы смогли:

```
Parent** parents;
Child** children;

// ...

parents = children;
```

Теперь вы сможете добавить указатель на `Parent` в массив `children`! Видите, как? Очень просто:

```
parents[0] = &parent;
```

А это уже плохо, потому что в массиве `children` не может быть указателей на `Parent`: что будет, если вы вызовете

```
children[0]->ChildSpecificMethod();
```

?

Comment: И оба раза запустится только конструктор класса Parent? А мне нужно, что бы во втором случае создались 5 указателей на объекты Child. То есть мне нужно, что бы конструктор Child тоже обязательно выполнился.

Comment: @Евгений Василенко: Ваш код не вызывает конструкторы! Он только заказывает указатели на объекты, конструкторы будут вызваны вами потом. Если вы напишете `pointer[0] = new Child()`, вызовется всё равно нужный конструктор.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Я понял суть. Возможно я неправильно решил это применить. Если есть лучшее решение, то подскажите.
Просто мне в моей программе нужен массив указателей, чтобы использовать виртуальность. И в то же время, для каждого объекта класса Foo он неизвестен на этапе компиляции. Мне ничего умнее, чем указатель на указатель не пришло. Собственно, я поэтому вопрос и задавал. А Ваш совет я уже опробовал, всё получилось, как хотел.

Comment: @Евгений Василенко: ваша идея в принципе правильная, но я на вашем месте бы вместо массива указателей использовал `std::vector<Parent*>`. В этом случае вам не придётся самостоятельно думать о выделении и освобождении памяти. Возможно, ещё лучшим решением был бы `std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Parent> >`, если вы не хотите контролировать время жизни объектов вручную. Явное использование сишных массивов и указателей в принципе считается пережитком прошлого.

Comment: @VladD Я боюсь Вам код показывать. Там полный хаос творится. Просто сначала было одно задание, а потом оно "выросло". Вот из-за этого и пришлось так усложнять.

Comment: @Евгений Василенко: не стыдно написать плохой код, стыдно будет, если вы не будете улучшать свой стиль с каждым новым проектом.

Comment: @VladD, задание явно учебное, так что пусть пока с голыми указателями и массивами покрутиться, это полезно. А вообще, во многих смыслах, вариантом лучшим, чем использование векторов с умными указателями, является библиотека boost::Pointer Container http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html]

Comment: @VladD, я сейчас работаю Junior'ом в одной компании. Code-review и советы постоянны. Кое-какой успех есть.
@mikillskegg, это не задание. Точнее, это программа для подсчёта экономической эффективности предприятий в аграрном секторе. Одна знакомая девушка пишет диссертацию по этой теме, перелопатила кучу всяких моделей (Альтмана, Бивера, Терещенко...) и создала свою. И вот именно её модель немного отличалась. Пришлось использовать виртуальность. Ну, а дальше пошло-поехало...